# Layover in New York city

Tags: air-travel, usa, customs-and-immigration, layovers, new-york-city

As a UE citizen with American B1/B2 visa I have 10 h layover in NY before I travel to Rio. Is it possible to leave an airport after I arrive from Europe and then check in again after layover?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What is UE?  Though it's not particularly relevant in this case.

Comment: @Karlson *Union Européenne*?

Comment: @phoog Or a typo for UAE.

Comment: @Karlson or for UA

Comment: Or for 'Bhutan'.

Comment: The US doesn't do airside transit, so you *must* clear US immigration and customs even on international-international connections.

Comment: Please see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23967/ive-got-five-hours-in-ny-what-places-can-i-visit-in-that-time/23974#23974

Answer (score 2):

it's unclear if you're asking if you are **allowed** to (visa rules) or if it's worth doing / do you have enough time with ten hours titularly.  Assuming you mean "is it worth doing..."

If you are happy to just **take a taxi** both ways (and it's not a problematic traffic time of day), I'd say yeah just go straight in to Manhattan. I'd choose ahead of time a typical Manhattan restaurant; go straight there, see **the skyline** on the way in, have a meal, relax, **walk around** a little, and go straight back to your Rio flight.

I wouldn't be complicated in choosing a restaurant, just have lunch at The Plaza or the like, so you see the **main areas** from the taxi ride (Central Park, etc). If you try to choose some insider hip place or whatever, the timing will work against you or it will be full, etc.

Conversely if you ate enough on the plane, and prefer to stretch your legs just go to **MOMA**.

That's about what you have time for (again, just keep an eye on road traffic),

If you have not been to NYC before, note that if you're from Dubai (your question has a typo, as mentioned in the comments), it's probably rather pointless going "in to Manhattan". You'll just see an ancient, amazingly tedious, version of "big city", you presently live in one of today's actual "big cities" so there's not much point.

(I.E., you'll get to see things as thrillingly exciting as "branches of The Gap". Regarding say "large buildings", if you're from Mumbai, Shanghai, Dubai or whatever you won't notice any. Regarding "culture", ok you can drive around downtown for 5 minutes and see where Blondie came from back in the last century, while observing the other branches of "The Gap".)

Comment: You don't need to assume New York City as it is explicit in the title.  It would therefore have to be Newark or JFK.  The latter is perhaps more likely as it is actually in the city of New York.  Depending on the time of year and the state of the traveler, it might be more attractive to go and have a nap on the beach.  It's certainly closer than Manhattan.

Comment: the title was edited

Comment: The edit history shows that the first version of the title was "Layover in New York city"

Comment: ah ok my mistake. I must have misread it.  thank God that is sorted out

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a visa **yes** you're allowed to leave an airport but you will have all your bags with you when you do.

Comment: It would likely be possible to recheck the bags immediately and then go to the beach (or whatever) for a few hours.

Comment: Doesn't one usually re-drop one's bags immediately after customs when landing in the US for a layover? Is there something specific to NY airports that says you can't leave the airport if you have done so?

Comment: @HenningMakholm From what I saw the transit desk funnels passengers back up to security and gates.

Comment: It's usually possible to leave at that point. At some airports, you could go to the transit area, drop your bags, and then turn the other way to go out the exit. At worst, you could go through security and then exit the airport through the normal domestic exit, but you'd have to go through security again when you came back of course.

Comment: Huhwhat? The US procedure is immigration-customs, now you are outside, as a convenience some airline-airport combos allow dropping the bags at this point but sometimes you need to go to the check in desk to drop them but you are definitely landside at this point.

Comment: Indeed, the baggage drop at JFK is immediately after exiting the customs area. You have to pass by it to get to departure, change terminals, or airport exit. There's no need to carry bags around with you all day.